# google maps api v3 - map data white block covers map

Tags: google-maps

When I load a google map, the whole map loads, however within a split second, a "map data" block covers most of the map - this has the text "Map" and a link "Map Data" on it.
(white block).

How do I stop this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Generally this means that the API has determined you have contravened the Terms, perhaps by obscuring things which should not be obscured. A link would be good (rather than code, because CSS may be involved).

Answer (score 0):

OK - the problem was CSS.  Any Maps - GoogleMaps, BING maps etc do not work if you set DIVs to have:

overflow: hidden

Phew!

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to have it hidden or `display:none`, it wont work. I work it around using jQuery with `$('#id').hide();`